# Stop a collection view deselecting an item

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` that is a calendar. It's a single scrollable row. Some of the dates are unselectable as there is no data for that date. Others ARE selectable as there IS data for that date.

When a date is selected the calendar underlines the selected date and scrolls it to the center of the `UICollectionView`.

When a date is tapped that doesn't have a date I have this function...

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return //is there data for the date at this indexPath?
}
```

This stops those cells being selected... however, it still deselects the previously selected cell.

There is a `shouldDeselect` function but I can't use this as I don't know the index of the tapped cell. So I can't determine whether the item should be deselected.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Did you try setting `collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection` as true?

Comment: @ebby94 I didn't do that because it should only allow single selection. The problem I'm having is when I'm telling it that it should NOT select an item, it is still deselecting the previously selected item.

Comment: Hate to resurrect this, however I recently had this issue in Xamarin iOS, and the simplest way to get this to work as desired was to set AllowsMultipleSelection to True. Because the rest of the code clears and sets a single distinct selected item, it did not cause 'multiple selected items' to result - so it worked well. My use case was a custom Calendar control, based on a CollectionView, and the MTWTFSS across the top should not be selectable, and have no effect on previously selected items. This then worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

It simple works for me when I reload the collectionview:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // return true whithout reloadData when necessarily
    collectionView.reloadData()
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue and I ended up with the following approach:

Whenever user selects a cell, remember the position in a member variable:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         myMemberVariable = indexPath.row
 }
```

After that call `myCollectionView.reloadData()`

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` apply appropriate configuration for the cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCell
    if indexPath.row == myMemberVariable && canSelectCellAt(indexPath: indexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = .green
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = .gray
    }

    return cell
}
```

Where `canSelectCellAt(indexPath: indexPath)` is a function, which returns `true` for selectable cells and `false` for non-selectable cells,

Comment: Ah, ok. Makes sense. I was thinking about storing the selected index. Will have a go. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this question (kind of late?) and to solve this you just need to use

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
```

Instead of shouldSelect

Comment: Thanks you, this works as expected (return false for items you don't want to allow selection for).

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

and in didSelect, deselect all previously selected index paths:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.filter({ $0 != indexPath }).forEach { indexPath in
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to enable multiple selection

```
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

and

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```